# Clear images from RenderWindowControl C# Activize.Net

Tags: vtk, dicom

I am using RenderWindowControl in order to display Dicom Series.
This way:

```
 string folder = path;//@"C:\VTKdata";
        vtkDICOMImageReader reader = vtkDICOMImageReader.New();
        reader.SetDirectoryName(folder);
        reader.Update();
  // Visualize
        _ImageViewer1 = vtkImageViewer2.New();
        _ImageViewer1.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort());
        _ImageViewer1.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

        _ImageViewer1.SetSlice(_MinSlice1);
        _ImageViewer1.Render();
```

I need to be able to delete all images displayed by the control, before the user reloads a new series.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the renderwindow by

```
_ImageViewer1.SetRenderWindow(null);
renderWindow.Render();
```

and simply connect it again if new data is available

```
_ImageViewer1.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
_ImageViewer1.Render();
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked:
var rw1 = _ImageViewer1.GetRenderWindow();
 _ImageViewer1.SetRenderWindow(null);
  rw1.Render();